# How to convert 4-point Spanish Grade Scale to 110-point Italian Grade Scale?

Tags: math

How can convert between the two grading system? The spanish 4-point scale and the Italian grade scale. I'm stuck in the problem because the a 2 in spain grade is like B grade in a ECTS usual scale and a cross-multiplication doesn't work.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_grading_in_Spain

[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_grading_in_Italy

Comment: My mistake, there is a 110 pt system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really accurately convert between two systems that have different precisions. Your best bet is to look at the corresponding approximate ECTS conversions for the both systems and estimate.

The conversion is non-linear so I would suggest doing a simple case-by-case conversion using if/switch statements.